# Find the probability that A and B are separated by a single painting and that A precedes B.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Six paintings, labelled A, B, C, D, E and F, are to be arranged in a row.
Assume each possible arrangement is equally likely. Find the probability that A and B are separated by a single painting and that A precedes B.

I tried to put it in the order A,C,B
also got $6!$ for the total number of ways it can be sorted out. I am just not sure how to get the value for A being separated by B

Comment: OK, what have you tried?

Comment: You need to tell us what you've tried, so that people can help you arrive at the solution. Also, fix the title

Answer (score 1):

For $A$ and $B$ to be separated by a single painting and that $A$ precedes $B$, exactly one of four scenarios can occur:

$A~\underline{~}~B~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}$

$\underline{~}~A~\underline{~}~B~\underline{~}~\underline{~}$

$~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~A~\underline{~}B~\underline{~}$

$\underline{~}~\underline{~}~\underline{~}~A~\underline{~}~B$

Pick which of those it was.

Then, from left to right, choose which painting was placed in the remaining open spots.

Apply rule of product and conclude.

> $4\cdot 4!$ satisfactory arrangements out of $6!$ total equally likely arrangements.

Comment: Thank you, got the answer after the first explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to fuse together A and B with AXB we count AXB as one painting so we have 4 paintings left counting AXB as one painting. So we have 4! Ways to arrange the 4 paintings we also have 4 choices for X so 4*4! Unique choices.